# 'this page can't be displayed' when using HTTPS

Tags: grails, https

for some actions in my Grails application i need to use HTTPS protocol , so i made the below filter :

```
def filters = {
    all(controller:'checkout', action:'onlinePayment') {
        before = {

            if (!request.isSecure() /*&& !Environment.isDevelopmentMode()*/) {

                def url = "https://" + request.serverName + request.forwardURI

                redirect(url: url, permanent: true)
                return false
            }
        }
```

but when i try to access this action , i get `this page can't be displayed` as seen in the screenshot[image]  and i'm geting in chrome's console `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`, are there any configurations i missed to be able to use HTTPS protocol ?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @SLaks i added screenshot to the original post

Comment: Check for error details in the devtools or in Chrome.

Comment: i'm getting `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: That means you aren't actually running a server on that port.

Comment: my server is running on 8080 port , shall i add to the filter to use 8443 port rather 8080 ?

Comment: Are you launching your application with `run-app -https`? You should be.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore no , what i want to make is to use HTTPS only for specific actions not for all the actions this is why i made that filter , if i used `run-app -https` it will use HTTPS for all actions

Comment: No, if you use `run-app -https` then your application will have 8443 port available for use. Otherwise only 8080 will be available and any attempt to use SSL will fail.

Comment: so is there a way while using HTTP in grails to move to HTTPS and vice versa, because using `run-app -https` will make all the application's actions run in HTTPS

Comment: Which version of Grails are you on? As @JoshuaMoore said, using `-https` does not force application to use all actions on https. Just run with this option and open `http://localhost:8080` and it should work.

Comment: @droggo, Grails 2.5.1 , you are right , i run the application using `-https` , and after editing the filter code url  part by adding the HTTPS port `8443` , when i try to access actions that use HTTPS it worked .. so in production environment , i shall start the application using `https` and access it via `http` as i did in development ?

Comment: In production you should use some application server/servlet container and configure it to have both http and https connectors. Configuration depends on software of your choice. You should not `grails run-app` production instance